# how to have an application helper method work when the sent request is JS formatted?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have a signed_in? method in rails that will drive u back to the landing page if you have been inactive for 5 minutes.

How do I make this work when the user clicks on a form submitted via js after the 5 minutes have passed? Obviously when this happens, the server sends the landing page back to the user, but it is not shown. Here is my signed_in method

```
def signed_in?
  unless current_user
    flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    if session[:expiry_time].nil? || session[:expiry_time] < 5.minutes.ago
      reset_session
      flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      session[:expiry_time] = 300.seconds.from_now
    end
  end
end
```

PS: I know it's horrible code, I'll be sure to refactor it :)

Answer (score 0):

But I'd start by implementing an alternate redirect method that does a full redirect even for XHR requests:

```
def redirect_with_js location
  if request.xhr?
    # HTML response is expected:
    render :text => "<script>document.location = '#{view_context.escape_javascript location}'</script>"
    # JS response is expected:
    # render :text => "document.location = '#{view_context.escape_javascript location}'"
  else
    redirect_to location
  end
end
```

Then use this method when redirecting:

```
redirect_with_js boomeranked_url
```

The returned text depends on what type of response the AJAX request expects to get back (HTML or JS). I've included both versions. This should give you something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with it, I find it simpler. In the signed_in method:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
      render 'home/not_logged_in'
    }
```

And then on the not_logged_in view

```
window.location = '<%= root_url %>';
```